# Android Bluetooth without Discovering and discoverability

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

My task is, to detect android devices, when reaching the propximity of some BT-Scanners(My PC)

Instead of discovering all visible devices:

- all Device BT MAC-Adresses are stored at my PC
- Can i look for special devices with the given MAC-adress without turning on discoverability on the android device? I don't want to turn on the discoverability all the time, so maybe I can check with the special MAC-adress for devices. Like the "ping" function in network technik?

I hope you understand my problem and hope for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one (or a few) device , the quickest approach is to try to do a connect to it to determine if it is available.